# How to use getElementById in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code in javascript:

```
<script>
var recognition;
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
    recognition.onresult = function(event) {
        if (event.results.length > 0) {
            q.value = event.results[0][0].transcript;
            q.form.submit();
        }
    }
}
</script>
<form action="http://www.example.com/search">
    <input type="search" id="q" name="q" size=60>
    <input type="button" value="Click to Speak" onclick="recognition.start()">
</form>
```

How do I use `getElementById` with AngularJS? The line `q.value = event.results[0][0].transcript;` is intended to insert what users input through speech recognition into an element `q` (which is used as a textbox). How do I do that in AngularJS?

Answer (score 2):

To get an element by its *id, class, attribute, etc.* you can use the built-in **[angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)**, which is a jQuery lite version for DOM manipulation.

> If `jQuery` is available, `angular.element` is an alias for the [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) function. If jQuery is not available, `angular.element` delegates to Angular's built-in subset of jQuery, called *"jQuery lite"* or *jqLite.*

```
var q = angular.element('#q');
q.val(event.results[0][0].transcript);
q.focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

You make use of the angular directive ng-model, add

`ng-model="speechtext"`

to your textfield and in your code you define the scope variable speechtext:

```
$scope.speechtext = q //or just the variable where the result is hold
```

Comment: so, after that I just use ``q.value`` as in javascript?

Comment: Yes, but with ng-model you tell the DOM Element what the content of itself will be. That's the Angular two-way binding, check it out here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel